# Proper RadioGroup in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

Is it possible to define a RadioGroup in a PreferenceActivity?
I could only find the ListView when offering multiple-choices.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to extend *any* `Preference` class. I did exactly what you are looking for  by extending `PreferenceCategory` for example. Add child preferences (such as `PreferenceScreen` and `EditTextPreference`) like normally with `addPreference()`, override it and change/ set the widget resource by code with `setWidgetLayoutResource()`. Naturally, your new widget should contain a `RadioButton`. Set a custom `OnPreferenceClickListener` with `setOnPreferenceClickListener()`.

Next get a reference to the `ViewGroup` "parent" in `onCreateView()`. Then you can cast it to `ListView` in `onBindView()`, and set a `OnHierarchyChangeListener` on it. Now you get notified when the child `Preference`'s `View`s are added to the `ListView`. Set a new `View.OnClickListener` on the new `View` in the hierarchy, but only if the `View` contains a `RadioButton`.  Now manage the clicks.

It's actually pretty easy if you only need to add `PreferenceScreen` as children. I also needed it with a `EditTextPreference`, which was the tricky part.

The benefits are simple: you get the default preference framework look and behaviour outside the context of a `ListPreference`. A `ListPreference` also looks different. Also, a `ListPreference` can only contain pre-defined values. So if you need a `EditTextPreference` to be selected with a radio button, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: This is more complicated and more fragile than simply extending `Preference` or `DialogPreference`. For example, you assume that the `ViewGroup` is a `ListView` (not guaranteed). Since you downvoted my answer, one would have hoped that you would have come up with something that is actually better, not worse.

Comment: All Preference views are normally attached to a `ListView`. I fail to see your point. Besides, there's always the possibility to add some checks.

Comment: "All Preference views are normally attached to a ListView" -- that is an implementation detail. Android 5.0 could change that. Do not create production code that depends on implementation details.

Comment: It could, but that's a problem for another day, and a whole other topic. Sticking to the SDK isn't a guarantee for forward compatibility either. The question was if it was possible. Yes, it is.

Comment: I never said it wasn't possible. You have not explained why your solution was better than mine, and therefore justified your downvote of my answer. And while "sticking to the SDK isn't a guarantee for forward compatibility either", that does not justify intentionally making things worse by assuming implementation details.

Comment: Making what things worse then what? You didn't provide any answer of the sort. A `DialogPreference` doesn't show it's options directly in a `PreferenceActivity`, I'm sure you know better then me, and subclassing it won't do any good either. The OP wants radio buttons on Preferences in the activity itself. Oh and from `PreferenceActivity`:  public ListView getListView(). Good luck hiding that, I guess 90% of the apps reply on this 'implementation detail'. Case closed.

Comment: "Good luck hiding that" -- it has been "hidden" for over two years. `PreferenceFragment` is not a `ListFragment`, and it is `PreferenceFragment` that hosts the `Preference` objects in modern code. I will readily admit that I should have mentioned just subclassing `Preference` in my answer. Doing that is a bit tricky to get right -- which is why I steered the OP towards sticking with dialogs -- but it will be more reliable than your approach, simply because it works within the confines of the preference framework, rather than assuming implementation details.

Comment: Well, `PreferenceActivity` extends `ListActivity` and still has this method readily available. But I took your advice and instead just added a listener on the `ViewGroup`. It's quite a hacky solution, I agree :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at API Demos App - Preferences - Preferences from XML or others examples.

You can basically copy that code. There is an entry that display a list with a radio group.

I don't have the code right now, but you can take a look here, it's similar:

http://www.kaloer.com/android-preferences

```
<ListPreference
                    android:title="List Preference"
                    android:summary="This preference allows to select an item in a array"
                    android:key="listPref"
                    android:defaultValue="digiGreen"
                    android:entries="@array/listArray"
                    android:entryValues="@array/listValues" />
```

Comment: All I can see there is a ListView. It's not the end of the world but would prefer a RadioGroup since it is a choice out of 3 possibilities. OTOH, if the standard way to go is ListView then I will stick with that.

Comment: The link you've provided is broken.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to define a RadioGroup in a PreferenceActivity?

You are welcome to create your own `DialogPreference` subclass that happens to host a `RadioGroup`, but it is unclear what benefit that would give you over a `ListPreference`.

> I could only find the ListView when offering multiple-choices.

A `ListPreference` offers single choices, not multiple choices. There is a new `MultiSelectListPreference` for multiple choices, but that only showed up in API Level 11.

Comment: > "but it is unclear what benefit that would give you"

The benefit is clear: one click less and UX. Observability (by user) of all possible choices in the containing dialog is expectable.

Comment: @avesus: "The benefit is clear: one click less and UX" -- clicking on a `RadioButton` is one click. Clicking on a `ListView` row is one click. "Observability (by user) of all possible choices in the containing dialog is expectable" -- the "observability" will be roughly equal, in that not everything will necessarily fit the screen, and so both options would need to support some form of scrolling.