# Android get checkbox on preferences

Tags: android, preferences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proper RadioGroup in PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087550/proper-radiogroup-in-preferenceactivity)

I've got a preferences file defined this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >      
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Group One" >
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionA"
                android:title="Option A" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionB"
                android:title="Option B" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionC"
                android:title="Option C" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Group Two" >
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionD"
                android:title="Option D" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionE"
                android:title="Option E" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionF"
                android:title="Option F" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
        <PreferenceCategory android:title="Group Tree" >
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionG"
                android:title="Option G" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionH"
                android:title="Option H" />
            <CheckBoxPreference
                android:defaultValue="false"
                android:key="optionI"
                android:title="Option I" />
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The idea is for the user only pick on option. If user checks `Option I`, this option gets checked but if he then checks `Option D`, `Option I` turns unchecked and `Option D` gets checked.

I want to know if it is possible to to this without using `ListPreferences`

If it was a dialog I would use `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` and iterate trough the items to accomplish want I want but I don't know ho to do this in preferences.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE

Following Gatekeeper suggestions this is the code:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceClickListener {

    final CheckBoxPreference optionA = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionA");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionB = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionB");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionC = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionC");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionD = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionD");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionE = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionE");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionF = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionF");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionG = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionG");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionH = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionH");
    final CheckBoxPreference optionI = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionI");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
        System.out.println("It gets here");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("This text is not printed on logcat");
        optionA.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionA.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionB.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionB.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionC.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionC.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionD.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionD.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionE.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionE.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionF.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionF.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionG.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionG.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionH.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionH.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
        optionI.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                unCheckAll();
                optionI.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }

    private void unCheckAll() {
        optionA.setChecked(false);
        optionB.setChecked(false);
        optionC.setChecked(false);
        optionD.setChecked(false);
        optionE.setChecked(false);
        optionF.setChecked(false);
        optionG.setChecked(false);
        optionH.setChecked(false);
        optionI.setChecked(false);

    }
}
```

My preferences are shown but after I click on an option it was supossed to all others be unckecked. This is not happening. Suggestions?

Comment: @AustynMahoney Sorry but forgot to tell I don't what to use `ListPreferences`

Comment: Is there a specific reason for this? It is the exact UI interaction you are asking for.

Comment: Yes. Because all the options mus be visible in that view

Comment: If you want that functionality, you need to code your own settings activity/fragment.

Comment: @AustynMahoney Ok. will probably do with a dialog then. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not quite sure why you wouldn't want to use a ListPreference, but either way what you need to do is when you go through the onClick() method of your preference you need to uncheck all of your checkboxes, then check just the checkbox you want.

Something like

```
optionD.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        unCheckAll();
        optionD.setChecked(true);
        return true;
    }
});

private void unCheckAll() {
    optionA.setChecked(false);
    optionB.setChecked(false);
    optionC.setChecked(false);
    // Rest of Options go here
}
```

**Update #2**

```
private CheckBoxPreference optionA;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    System.out.println("It gets here");

    optionA = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference("optionA");
    optionA.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            unCheckAll();
            optionA.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Do this example for all of your options. You are trying to find your options from a preference file before you call addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

Comment: Thanks. I believe that's it. I've implemented `OnClickListener` and have `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` I can cast that dialog to my preferences?

Comment: From my understanding you are trying to place your preferences view inside of a dialog?

Comment: Sorry if I mislead you. I have a menu (`MenuInflater`) and then my preferences are shown, just like a normal preferences. The dialog was just an example

Comment: Are you able to get the preferences to show within your menu? If so the above code should work no matter where your preferences are displayed.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for your answer. Sorry for my late responses but been away from the computer. Please see the updated code and thanks once again

Comment: May I also see your R.xml.prefs file please?

Comment: Done exactly that and still nothing. `System.out.println("This text is not printed on logcat");` does not get printed. The preference file is in the beginning of the OP. Thanks once again

Comment: Ok I finally figured it out and updated my answer with the solution! Place everything you have in your onPreferenceClick() method into your onCreate() method. The reason for this is because you need to call option.setOnPreferenceClickListener() on each of your preferences before they can receive a click event!

Comment: Many Many Many thanks. This is what I was aiming for. Thanks for you time and patience

Answer (score 1):

you can use code to do it. implement an onPreferenceChangedListener() an use the states to get the desired response.